# Why there is no direct interaction to other members on a SE site?

Tags: discussion, notifications

When I know my question is resolvable by a specific user, how should we notify him/her? I heard there is no direct interaction to the person. Why not?

Its not an personal message I'm asking about, just a notification to user who is very good at some tag.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, pls have a look at question again

Comment: @Shadow Wizard pls have a look at question again

Comment: How would you see this non-personal message? How would he/she be notified then?

Comment: Because Jon Skeet doesn't like to be drowned in inbox notifications.

Comment: @sameerjoshi I did. Still think it's duplicate. Notification that only the target user can see is actually a private message. It's just matter of wording.

Answer (score 5):

Because *everybody* would ask Jon Skeet (or any other top-scoring user) to solve his/her problem. That's not how it works.

How it does work:

- You ask a good question;
- You will receive votes;
- Users will see your post. The higher your votes, the most likely other users will notice it;
- Users who know the answer will post an answer;
- If you don't get an answer, or an answer that is not useful, you can place a bounty on your question.

Comment: you are right but some times we want an answer immediately, as if question is public i want some one to look up iam not forcing him to asnswer it just kind of notification.

Comment: If you want an immediate answer, you should hire someone.

Comment: +1 gr8 answer, unexpected answer

Comment: @sameerjoshi - If you want an immediate answer, hire somebody to give you one, your question would need to extremely good to get an immediate answer at Stackoverflow.  Don't ask questions that need immediate answers, you likely won't meet your goals, of getting an immediate answer.